# Flask Debug throws multithread sqlite3.ProgrammingError

Tags: python, multithreading, debugging, sqlite, sqlalchemy

A simple Python Flask SQLAchemy application works fine with `debug=False` but throws a multithreading error when accessing the database if `debug=True`.  It appears that debug restarts the app creating two threads.  The work-around appears to be making a connection to the database before each query. I am sure there is a more elegant way of solving with the 'g' but want to keep this simple at this stage.

Is this a Flask bug or an implementation issue?  I suspect the latter so any guidance appreciated.

Here is a simple version of the program that prints the db query to the console:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, select, Table
from flask import Flask


# create application
app = Flask(__name__)

sqlite_file = 'bankapi_db.sqlite'
sqlalchemy_dbpath = "sqlite:///" + sqlite_file


# Connecting to the database file
engine = create_engine(sqlalchemy_dbpath)
meta = MetaData()
conn = engine.connect()
accountz = Table('accounts', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)


print('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')


##########################################################################
# api_info
##########################################################################


@app.route('/')
def api_info():
    '''Display information'''

    # conn = engine.connect()

    s = select([accountz])
    rv = conn.execute(s)
    for row in rv:
        print(row)

    # conn.close()
    return "back at you"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)
```

With `debug=True` you can see the restart with the (++++++++) in the console:

```
$ python3 thread_test.py
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 738-768-392
```

Versus `Debug=False`:

```
 $ python3 thread_test.py
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```